# PHP making clickable links

Tags: php, html, html-entities

I have here a function that creates a clickable link:

```
function makeClickableLinks($text) {
        $notIncludedonLink = preg_replace('/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i', '', $text);  // removing not included on the link
        $urlLink = str_replace($notIncludedonLink,'',$text);
        $finalText = str_replace($urlLink,'<a href="'.$urlLink.'" target="_blank">'.$urlLink.'</a>',$text);
        return $finalText;
    }
```

But instead of returning plain clickable link:

```
http://docs.google.com/
```

it displays:

```
<a href="http://docs.google.com/" target="_blank">http://docs.google.com/</a>
```

I tried using `htmlentities` but it doesn't work.

Here's a JS code that sends data to server:

```
function checkNewLink() {
var latestId = $("input[name=latestLink]").val();
$('.newReply').load("links/ajax.php?action=newreply&msgid=<?php echo $msgId; ?>&latestid=" + latestId);
}
setInterval("checkNewLink()", 200);
```

where `latestId` contains the inputted link. It will be sent to ajax.php. Every 200 ms, it will check if there are new inputted link.

Comment: It's not understandable what are you trying to achieve here. Please explain your problem in more detail

Comment: what "$text" is containing?

Comment: It works well. What's your problem? Are you setting your output correctly like `text/html` instead of `text/plain`? Can we see the full code?

Comment: @Priyank `$text` contains the link `http://docs.google.com/`

Comment: I'm calling like `echo makeClickableLinks("http://docs.google.com/");` and its working. what is ur problem detailed here

Comment: I have to note that i am using jQuery's load and html, to view the link and JS's setInterval to check for new links.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
function makeClickableLinks($text){
    return preg_replace('!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $text);
}

echo makeClickableLinks('test http://docs.google.com/ test');
```

output code (http://codepad.org/EZE1HFZ4)

> test http://docs.google.com/ test

**AFTER UPDATE**

change

```
setInterval("checkNewLink()", 200);
```

to

```
setInterval(function(){ checkNewLink() }, 200);
```

read [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) Method

Comment: It's working man. But combining with jQuery and some other code, it's not. I'll paste some JS and jQuery snippets

Comment: @SimoneNigro still not working but thanks for the help. i will be working on this. :)